# How to clear previously drawn polygons before rotating Qpainter?

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to construct an odometer in qt.The Idea is that I draw a convex polygon using QPainter , and then I rotate the QPainter instance using the `QPainter::rotate()` function ,followed by a `QLabel::setPixmap()` to update it on the screen, however , I can see the previously drawn polygons , how can I get rid of them?I know of eraserect function , but I'm looking for a better alternative since eraserect erases the entire rectangle.Also, is there a way where I don't have to call setpixmap again and again? Here's the code:

```
for(int i=0;i<23;i++)
   {
     paint.rotate(8); // paint is a QPainter instance initialized with a QPixmap instance
    paint.drawConvexPolygon(pts , 3);
     ui->needle->setPixmap(pin);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to erase anything if you do all painting in `QWidget::paintEvent()`. You can trigger `paintEvent` by calling `update()` when state of the widget changes.

Comment: How would I go about intitialising the QPainter in that case.Since here I am initialising it with a QPixmap..Would QPainter(this) do the same work there?

Comment: Maybe you dont need any pixmap, you can draw everything on widget, post all related code

Comment: Try this library https://github.com/Berrima/Qt-custom-gauge-widget

Answer (score 0):

Either instantiate a new `QPixmap` and `QPainter` or clear the pixmap every time you want to change it using something like `QPixmap::fill` with a transparent fill color.